# How to fix always returning unathorized status of using [Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, user-roles

I am implementing role-based authentication for asp.net core webapi. I almost followed this tutorial. 
https://medium.com/@engr.mmohsin/asp-net-core-2-0-webapi-jwt-role-based-authentication-authorization-with-custom-tables-and-identity-401c898d9ef1

After I logged in with manage account `[Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]` always returns unauthorized.

In controller class

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
```

Genarating token in login method of service class

```
var claims = new[] {

    new Claim("Name", user.Name), 
    //few other claims
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role.ToString())


        };
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));

var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
          _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
          claims,
          expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
          signingCredentials: creds);
return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
```

In startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    });
```

Someone, please explain what is the issue of this code?

HTTP Request
[image: e]

**Solved :  This happen not reaching the code app.UseAuthentication()**

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine enough. When you are sending a token in the header of your HTTP Request. Have you appended the authorization type?

You need an authorization type in the header of your HTTP Request
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

Check the Authentication Schemes here
http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml

What you need is bearer authentication scheme. You can read this link  for more information on the specifics
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1

So, your authorization header would look like

```
httpClient.DefaultHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + your token);
```

And you can get it to work with your current setup by using it like

```
[Authorize("Bearer", (Roles = "Manager")]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I'm sending authorization type with http request. (just added a image to question). `[Authorize("Bearer", (Roles = "Manager")]` dosen't work gave me an exception.

Comment: What exception, does it give?

Did you try without the Roles Manager part? [Authorize("Bearer")]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.I'm so dumb.
Reason for this issue is not using `app.UseAuthentication();`

In my case, I have accidentally added this to production environment scope. kind of like this....

```
else if (env.IsProduction())
   {
       ....
       app.UseAuthentication();
   }
```

My program running on developement enviroment. So `app.UseAuthentication();` not reaching.